# Examples to help understand discrete metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces

I have been asked to provide examples (or proofs that none exist) regarding some points and subsets of *discrete metric spaces*. I believe I can set the interval/segment that the discrete metric space covers, I just have to provide a valid example that fits/shows the definition of these (among other) definitions:

1 - A **neighborhood** of a point *p* 
is  a   set *Nr(P)* 
consisting 
of all points 
*q* 
such 
that 
*d(p, 
q) 
< 
r*. 
The 
number 
*r* 
is called 
the 
radius 
of *Nr(p)*.

2 - A 
point 
*p* 
is  a 
**limit point** 
of 
the  set 
*E* 
if 
every 
neighborhood 
of 
*p* 
contains a 
point 
*q 
$\neq$ 
p* 
such 
that 
*q 
$\in$
E*.

3 - *E* 
is 
**closed** 
if 
every 
limit 
point of 
*E* 
is a 
point of 
*E*.

Even if you cannot provide examples for all of the points and subsets, I would very much appreciate help with any of them. I can try to piece together the others. Also, just to clarify, there are several other definitions I have to provide examples for, these are just a few to help me better understand the concept.. Thanks for looking into my problem!

Comment: Hint: fix a point $p$ and consider the open and closed balls of radius $\frac12$. What does this tell you about the set $\{p\}$?

Comment: @Math1000 Is this in reference to number 2? From what I can gather, in a discrete metric space, there are no limit points. Which (of course) implies for number 3 that all of the limit points are contained in E (since there are none). Does that make sense? If so, would you mind doing me a huge favor and helping me put it into words that make sense for a math course? I think that's most of the problem I'm having..

Comment: We have for each $p$: $$\left\{q : d(p,q)<\frac12\right\} = \{p\}.$$ The union of open sets is open, so therefore what can we conclude about the open sets in space?

Comment: That each point in the space is an *isolated point*?

Comment: @Math1000 You'll have to forgive me, I'm new to these concepts and trying to get a grasp on them. So I'm really not sure what to conclude from these hints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $E$ is a nonempty set, the map $$d(p,q)=\begin{cases} 1,&p\ne q\\0,& p=q\end{cases} $$
induces the *discrete topology* on $E$ - that is, every set of $E$ is open. For if $p\in Q$ then $$\left\{q\in E:d(p,q)<\frac12\right\}=\{p\} $$ is open, and thus for any $S\subset E$ we have $$S=\bigcup_{p\in S}\{p\}, $$ so that $S$ is open.

We also conclude that every point of $E$ is an isolated point, since e.g. the neighborhood of $p$ with radius $\frac12$ does not contain a point $q\ne p$. This means that every subset of $E$ is closed, since there are no limit points in $E$.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.. I think I can get the rest of them with those examples. I was mostly having trouble putting things into words, and I wanted to be sure I understood metric sets properly before doing all of the questions. Which I believe I do, now! :)

Comment: I've found another problem I'm stuck on, if you don't mind giving me a hand... I'm trying to find an example of an interior point of a discrete metric space, but I don't fully understand what that entails. Do you mind helping me out?